# How to add bookmark to Nautilus 3.6?

Tags: 12.10, nautilus

I updated the Nautilus to 3.6 in Ubuntu 12.10, but I didn't find the how to add my folder to "Bookmark" section.

If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>, it show the list of bookmarks, but I can't add any. I can't drag & drop just like in other versions.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The bookmarks will be at nautilus

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks
```

You can edit this file to change your bookmarks.

This also work in Ubuntu 13.04, with Nautilus 3.6.3 .

If in doubt, use `nautilus --version` to see which version you have.

Answer (score 44):

As of Ubuntu 13.04, apparently, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> adds a bookmark to the folder you're in.

Comment: Now it's working with ctrl+D, the problem was with 12.10

Comment: Easier than it looks like.

Comment: Not having to edit a config file is what using Ubuntu is all about! :)  They could have made it more discoverable in UI though.

Comment: Works in 12.04 as well.

Answer (score 3):

For **Nautilus 3.4** I'm not able to drag to create bookmarks either.

I add them editing `~/.gtk-bookmarks`. If you don't have that file create it. Example:

```
$ cat .gtk-bookmarks
file:///home/my_username/Software
file:///home/my_username/Ebooks
```

Try it out.

Comment: I tried, but only show the folder I had in bookmarks in 3.4. I think that in 3.6 it use something different.

Answer (score 2):

### Ubuntu 14.04 and later

1. Open Files file browser.
2. Browse to the folder that you want to bookmark and open it.
3. From the Files menu select *Bookmarks* ->*Bookmark this location* to bookmark the folder. You can also bookmark the folder by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.
4. A new heading called **Bookmarks** will be created in the pane on the left side of Files file browser if it does not already exist, and you can find the new bookmark that you created under the Bookmarks heading.