# Using Ubuntu, how do i connect to a windows share on my Windows Server 2008

Tags: server, windows

I'm switching from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.10,,, In Windows, to access my server, all I have to do is open credential manager and add my servername, username, and password,,, and it works, I have access to all my shared folders. I then would map network drives so I could access them with ease.

In Ubuntu, how do I go about doing this. I would like for these shares to be available in the left pane when I open the home folder. I also need them to be available no matter how many times I reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:
Open "Home", go to "File > Connect to server".

This way you can connect to your Windows share and even stored the credentials in secure store (see application named "Passwords and Keys").

Please note that this will make the share accessible by using the Gnome's GVFS, which works pretty well for all gnome-aware applications. However, I've experienced problems when I tried opening Word document directly from such network folder (by using Microsoft Word started by Crossover...on the other hand, this works well with LibreOffice)

Comment: thank you so much,,, I added one of my shares, and am going to do a restart to see if it stays there

Comment: I restarted, and it is no longer there, when I tried to do it again, now it says "failed to mount windows share"

Comment: You can also BOOKMARK shares (in menu) so it will not disappear after restart.
regarding the "failed to mount" error, have you allowed the system to remember the credentials (forever)?

Comment: how do I go about bookmarking? It's been a while since I've used ubuntu

Comment: It should be available from the menu as well.
Simply access your (remote) folder, go to menu ("sun" icon on the right side of the "Home" window) and select "Bookmark this location".

Maybe this will also help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/258416/how-to-add-bookmark-to-nautilus-3-6