# Partition not showing as device in Nautilus

Tags: partitioning, nautilus

I have mounted a partition as ext4 and define in `/etc/fstab`.

```
UUID=4xxxxxx-xxxxx /wdd ext4    defaults 0  2
```

I can see the mount point as `/wdd` running `df -k`.

But it is not showing up as device under Nautilus. I wish it is found there. I search and found a post saying that I need to mount under `/media`. I do not want to mount under `/media`. Is there a way there?

Comment: Yes. Use [Nemo](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nemo/).

Answer (score 1):

You could add it as a bookmark. Just add the line `file:///wdd` to file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. For more details see [How to add bookmark to Nautilus 3.6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/258416/how-to-add-bookmark-to-nautilus-3-6)

Comment: It worked!. Thanks for the workaround. Can know the rational behind why it is not showing under devices?

Comment: I guess because you added it to fstab so it is not a hot-pluggable device any more. If you want to experiment remove it from there and reboot. You should see it in devices but it will not be mounted automatically. Click on it to mount it then create a symlink /wdd pointing to /media/<user>/4xxxxx. It is not quite the same (no automount) but you will see it in Devices.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to mount it under `/media` and make `/wdd` a link to the mount point. Make your `fstab` like this:

```
UUID=4xxxxxx-xxxxx /media/wdd ext4    defaults 0  2
```

Then, remove the existing `/wdd` directory and recreate it as a link:

```
sudo rmdir /wdd; sudo ln -s /media/wdd/ /wdd
```

---

You can also try the reverse approach but I;m not sure if nautilus will pick it up:

```
sudo ln -s /wdd /media/wdd
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! I am seeing the drive appearing under devices as soon as I mount it as /media/wdd.

Comment: @haans glad to hear it! If one of these answers solves your issue please take a minute and click the check mark under the vote count to the left, this will [signify to everyone](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) that your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Tried the reverse approach. Didn't work. I just used what Smurf suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is a bit old, but it's coming up as a top google search. By default Nautilus/Caja automatically show devices mounted in`/media`. This policy may be overriden by use of the options `x-gvfs-show`. So your fstab entry would look like:

```
UUID=4xxxxxx-xxxxx /wdd ext4    defaults,x-gvfs-show 0  2
```